# How do I programmatically upload pictures to facebook?

Tags: facebook, api, javascript, html, asp.net

Ok, so here was my first question:
[How do I allow visitors on my site to share my photos on their facebook news feed?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10140/how-do-i-allow-visitors-on-my-site-to-share-my-photos-on-their-facebook-news-feed)

After implementing it I realized what I really want is to upload the image as a photo to their photo album.

How would I got about getting an image on my site, to upload to their photo album, when they click on a facebook icon next to the image?

Any thoughts at all are appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Register your application](http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php) at Facebook (create a Facebook app).

[Authenticate](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication) the user with Facebook, at the same time user approves your app access.

Use Facebook [publishing api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) to upload image (follow link, look for Publishing title).

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that you are authorized to publish to the user's feed with the **publish_stream** permission.

Then use the api commands to send the photo to the server.

Here's an example using the [Branches FB API](http://fbapi.blogspot.com):

```
Dim FB As New SessionInfo("[access_token]")
Dim Posts = New Functions.Posts(FB)
Dim img As String = "[Local picture Location]"
Dim F = New IO.FileStream(img, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
Dim B(F.Length - 1) As Byte
F.Read(B, 0, B.Length)
F.Close()
Dim PhotoID = Posts.PublishPhoto("[Album ID]", "[caption]", true, B, [Optional Tags if any])
```

Tagging users is similar, just pass in a tag list when you call PublishPhoto

```
 Dim TL As New List(Of Tag)
 Dim T As New Tag
 T.id = "[userID]"
 TL.Add(T)
 Dim PhotoID = Posts.PublishPhoto("["me" or Album ID]", "[caption]", true, B, TL)
```