# Share image from Android app to facebook , with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, share

I'm looking for (working) solution of sharing image issue.
I use Facebook SDK and everything is working fine in sharing except of putting image in parameters.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmCanvas.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
parameters.putParcelable("picture",bmCanvas);
parameters.putString("name", "caption");
parameters.putString("description", "description");
parameters.putString("caption", "caption");
fb.dialog(CanvasActivity.this, "feed",parameters,new DialogListener(){ ....
```

i was trying with all of the options, i mean putting a picture parameter with uri, but also doesn't work.
The diallog with post on facebook is apearing but the image content is not loaded, and when i accept publishing the post, it's published but without photo.
Can anyone help me?
Or there is somebody who succesfully posted image from android internal or external storage to wall on facebook?

Comment: try using facebook graph api explorers: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/   

You'l then know first if the code is a prob or behaviour from facebook

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18198025/facebook-wall-post-with-text-and-image    
   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429923/how-do-i-programmatically-upload-pictures-to-facebook

Answer (score 0):

try using `parameters.putByteArray("picture", bmCanvas);`

instead of `parameters.putParcelable("picture",bmCanvas);`